# how to exceeds 64K limit using jaggery

Tags: javascript, jaggery-js

I am using jaggery. I have a page very big  (HTML and jaggery) and I receive:

> Generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit

I need know if exist any way to pass this restriction.

Comment: *But 64K ought to be enough for anyone!*

Comment: yes, 64k ougth to be enough. I rewrote my code, but only ask by curiosity. Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a limitation on the Rhino Engine. Jaggery uses Rhino to compile Js files into Java bytecodes. On the latest Jaggery this should be solved.

As an alternative you could try separating your single file into multiple files and use [require](http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=require) keyword to import.